# C# to C#, convenience language features

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to learn what are all the convenience features of C#, and how they map to C#.

For example, automatic properties:

```
public string Foo { get; set; }
```

...maps to something like this:

```
string <Foo>k__BackingField;

[CompilerGenerated]
public string Foo {
   get { return this.<Foo>k__BackingField; } 
   set { this.<Foo>k__BackingField = value; } 
}
```

Foreach loops:

```
foreach(char c in "Hello") {
   Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

...maps to something like this (I think):

```
CharEnumerator en;

try {

   en = "Hello".GetEnumerator();

   while (en.MoveNext()) {
      char c = en.Current;

      Console.WriteLine(c);
   }

} finally {

   IDisposable disp = en as IDisposable;

   if (disp != null)
      disp.Dispose();
}
```

The disposing of the enumerator makes `foreach` very useful when dealing with unmanaged resources, like looping through lines in a file, or records in a database.

I think a good understanding of these high level features can help us write better code. What are other convenience features of C#, and how do they map to C#?

Comment: Are you asking how C# maps to C#?

Comment: Seems maxtoroq wants to collect how some "convenience" features are expanded in the plain C#. Who's going to show the using(){} construct? :) try-finally and maybe check for null before calling Dispose in the finally part. Right?

Comment: Actually, in `foreach` it is important that the `char c` is **outside** the loop, to explain the infamous capture issue.

Comment: Does that foreach really get converted to that?  OMG yes, we can edit comments now!

Comment: All of the high-level constructs which map to low-level constructs are described in the specification.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to talk about the amount of code saved, the biggest savers (IMO) are:

**iterator blocks**

Example:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Get() {yield return 1; yield return 2;}
```

Saved:

- writing an `IEnumerable<T>` implementation
- writing an `IEnumerator<T>` implementation
- handling state of the enumerator; have you **seen** how horrible it is? Seriously.

**captured variables** (anon methods / lambdas)

Example:

```
var list2 = list1.FindAll(x => (x.Value % 10) == find);
```

Saved:

- writing a class to hold the state

  - in complex cases, nested state
- initializing the state wrapper
- writing a method on that class

**Expression lambda compiler**

Example (from above):

```
Expression<Func<Foo,bool>> pred = x => (x.Value % 10) == find;
```

Saved:

- yeuch - lots of tree code; very, very complex; in the above I can see (in no particular order) `Expression.Parameter`, `Expression.Property`, `Expression.Field`, `Expression.Constant`, `Expression.Equal`, `Expression.Modulo`, `Expression.Lambda`... combine ;-p

Answer (score 8):

using is syntax sugar

```
using(x) 
{
    ...
}
```

Maps to

```
try {
    // Code
}
finally
{
    if(x != null)
        ((IDisposable)x).Dispose();
}
```

The from- thing in LINQ is syntactic sugar

```
from x in l where y select z;
```

translates to

```
l.Where(x => y).Select(x => z);
```

Comment: This is close but not quite correct.  It actually calls ((IDisposable)x).Dispose().

Answer (score 6):

[**LINQ**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx) as a whole (especially using the LINQ query syntax) is essentially a major C#/.NET convenience feature that replaces for-loops/iterators/complex query logic much of the time.

Answer (score 5):

1. `for`, `while`, `do`...`while`, `switch` -- a controversial answer :)

   You could replace it with some code based on `if` and `goto`.
2. `lock(){}` could be translated to Monitor.Enter() and Monitor.Exit() within a try-finally with null check (see [Does a locked object stay locked if an exception occurs inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590159/in-c-does-a-locked-object-stay-locked-if-an-exception-occurs-inside-it/590174#590174) )

Answer (score 4):

[The ?: operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx), which tests a boolean or boolean expression and returns the first value if the test returns `true` and the second value if the test returns `false`:

`condition ? first_expression : second_expression`

Which essentially means:

```
var x;
if (condition)
{
    x = first_expression;
}
else
{
    x = second_expression
}
```

Using the ?: operator, you can write `int x = condition ? 10 : 20;` instead of having to write out the whole `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Object initializers are pretty syntax sugar:

```
 public class Book
{
 public string Author { get; set; }
 public string Title { get; set; }
}

Book book = new Book() {Author = "John Smith", Title = "C# Syntax"};
```

The above is another way to write:

```
Book book = new Book();
book.Author = "John Smith";
book.Title = "C# Syntax";
```

Implicit types:

```
var book = new Book() {Author = "John Smith", Title = "C# Syntax"};
```

Comment: how does this map to C# without using object initializers?

Comment: should be pretty obvious: invoking setters one by one right after the ctor call.

Comment: BTW "anonymous type" example doesn't look right for me, because you have a normal Book type there. is it typo and should be `var book = new {Author = "John Smith", Title = "C# Syntax"};` instead? :)

Comment: That wasn't an anonymous type example.  It was implicit typing.

Answer (score 3):

The [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) (??) can be pretty nifty.  This ...

```
ISomeRef myRef = firstChoice ?? secondChoice ?? fallback;
```

Translates to something functionality equivalent to:

```
ISomeRef myRef = firstChoice;
if(myRef == null) myRef = secondChoice;
if(myRef == null) myRef = fallback;
```

I say functionally equivalent because I haven't looked in reflector yet :)

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous types:

```
var message = new { Message = "Hello, world!", MessageID = 1 };
```

is translated to

```
<>f__AnonymousType0<string, int> message =
    new <>f__AnonymousType0<string, int>("Hello, world!", 1);
```

where

```
[CompilerGenerated]
[DebuggerDisplay(
    @"\{ Message = {Message},
    MessageID = {MessageID} }",
    Type="<Anonymous Type>"
 )
]
internal sealed class <>f__AnonymousType0<
    <Message>j__TPar,
    <MessageID>j__TPar
> {
    // Fields
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly <Message>j__TPar <Message>i__Field;
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly <MessageID>j__TPar <MessageID>i__Field;

    // Methods
    [DebuggerHidden]
    public <>f__AnonymousType0(
        <Message>j__TPar Message,
        <MessageID>j__TPar MessageID
    ) {
        this.<Message>i__Field = Message;
        this.<MessageID>i__Field = MessageID;
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    public override bool Equals(object value) {
        var type = value as <>f__AnonymousType0<
            <Message>j__TPar,
            <MessageID>j__TPar
        >;
        return (((type != null) && 
            EqualityComparer<<Message>j__TPar>.Default.Equals(
                this.<Message>i__Field, 
                type.<Message>i__Field)
            ) &&
            EqualityComparer<<MessageID>j__TPar>.Default.Equals(
                this.<MessageID>i__Field,
                type.<MessageID>i__Field)
            );
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    public override int GetHashCode() { 
        int num = 0x2e22c70c;
        num = (-1521134295 * num) +
            EqualityComparer<<Message>j__TPar>.Default.GetHashCode(
                this.<Message>i__Field
            );
        return ((-1521134295 * num) +
            EqualityComparer<<MessageID>j__TPar>.Default.GetHashCode(
                this.<MessageID>i__Field)
            );
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    public override string ToString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("{ Message = ");
        builder.Append(this.<Message>i__Field);
        builder.Append(", MessageID = ");
        builder.Append(this.<MessageID>i__Field);
        builder.Append(" }");
        return builder.ToString();
    }

    // Properties
    public <Message>j__TPar Message {
        get {
            return this.<Message>i__Field;
        }
    }

    public <MessageID>j__TPar MessageID {
        get {
            return this.<MessageID>i__Field;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous delegates get changed into methods during compilation, so this:

```
var collection = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }.Where(i => i == 2);
```

causes a new method to be created:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private static bool <Main>b__0(int i)
{
    return (i == 2);
}
```

and changes to:

```
IEnumerable<int> collection = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }.Where<int>(<Main>b__0);
```

Notice that it uses a method name that you cannot create before compiling `<Main>b__0` - you cannot have `<>` in a method name, so it always avoid collisions.

The same process happens to this as well as `i => i == 2`:

```
delegate(int i) { return i == 2; }
```

You will also notice that you can use short hand for:

```
new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
// goes to...
new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

and

```
var foo = new Foo();
// goes to...
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

Lambda expressions are another example.

```
var myZombies = myMonsters.Where(monster => monster.Kind == MonsterKind.Zombie);
```

pulls out the Lambda delegate into its own method with a weird name.

You can use the Reflector and switch between the C# versions in the options dialogue to see the differences of how such things would be resolved.

Comment: Strictly speaking it only does this for delegate types (the above syntax could also work with `Expression` types, but is implemented completely differently)

Answer (score 1):

`Nullable<T>` is another incredible convenience. Especially handy is the `?` syntax as in `int?` is short for `Nullable<int>`.

Comment: Plus the ? shortcut for Nullable<T>, as in int? or bool?

Answer (score 1):

Extension methods.

If this is your extension method:

```
static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public void ExtensionMethod(this object obj)
    {
        // Do something here...
    }
}
```

And you call `obj.ExtensionMethod()`

It translates to:

`ObjectExtensions.ExtensionMethod(obj)`

If you happen to have a version of the C# compiler that supports extension methods, you can trick the compiler into letting you use extension methods in versions of .Net prior to 3.5 by creating a `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute`, like this: (It is perfectly safe to do this, since the compiler maps the extension methods into standard IL)

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    using System;

    internal sealed class ExtensionAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: [Except](http://doogalbellend.blogspot.com/2008/11/predefined-type-is-defined-in-multiple.html) when it's [not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990536/compilation-errors-with-imageresizer-3-2-1).

Answer (score 0):

Unusual amongst high level languages, C# has a 'goto' statement and consequently several other C# statements can be considered to be language translations into the goto statement.

For example, the if() statement maps directly to a goto while the standard for() loop actually maps to a while() loop which maps to a goto.

The switch() statement is unusual as it is compiled differently depending on number of cases and type of the switch argument. Thus it is not possible to consider it a language transformation to goto.

Answer (score 0):

Collection initializers (and type inference):

```
var scoobies = new List<Scooby>()
        {
            new Scooby("Buffy"),
            new Scooby("Willow"),
            new Scooby("Xander")

        };
```

Maps to:

```
List<Scooby>() scoobies = new List<Scooby>();
scoobies.Add(new Scooby("Buffy"));
scoobies.Add(new Scooby("Willow"));
scoobies.Add(new Scooby("Xander"));
```