# try and lock question

Tags: c#, .net

i have a question .. is it ok if i have something like this :

```
try 
{ 
    lock(programLock) 
    {
         //some stuff 1
    }
}
catch(Exception ex) { //stuff 2 }
```

i am curious if `"some stuff 1"` causes an exception , does `programLock` still remains locked ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, the lock will be released, lock is roughly equivalent to this:

```
try
{
    Monitor.Enter(programLock);
    // some stuff 1
}
finally
{
    Monitor.Exit(programLock);
}
```

(Meaning if an exception is thrown, `Monitor.Exit` will get called automatically as you exit the scope of the lock statement)

Answer (score 6):

`Lock()` is nothing but

```
try
{
   Monitor.Enter(...);
}
finally
{
   Monitor.Exit(....);
}
```

So it already takes care of it.

Answer (score 4):

From [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx)

> "... lock or SyncLock insures that the
>   underlying monitor is released, even
>   if the protected code throws an
>   exception."

note: You can create your own exception safe blocks for arbitrary actions with [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) blocks, .net's version of the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom.

Answer (score 2):

No. leaving the lock braces will always unlock.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not remain locked.

The "closing brace" of the lock is basically the finally clause of the Monitor.Exit.

See this associated StackOverflow Question.

[Does a locked object stay locked if an exception occurs inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590159/in-c-does-a-locked-object-stay-locked-if-an-exception-occurs-inside-it)