# Exception during lock

Tags: c#, locking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In c# does a locked object stay locked if an exception occurs inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590159/in-c-sharp-does-a-locked-object-stay-locked-if-an-exception-occurs-inside-it)

What happens when you have code such as this

```
  lock(myLock)
  {
    try{
      //some code
    }catch(SomeException e)
    {
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

Will myLock get released properly? I have a situation where this is necessary, so how would I go about it short of writing my own Lock that has an explicit Release method I can call in the try catch's finally method.?