# Finally is not executed when in a Thread running in a Windows Service

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services, try-catch-finally

Can anyone explain why this finally block is not executed? I have read posts about when to expect finally block not be executed, but this seems to be another case. This code needs TopShelf and log4net. I am running .net 4.5

I guess it must be the Windows Service engine that kicks in on unhandled exceptions, but why is it running before the finally block has finished?

```
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Topshelf;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class HostMain
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HostFactory.Run(x =>
            {
                x.Service<HostMain>(s =>
                {
                    s.ConstructUsing(name => new HostMain());
                    s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());
                    s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());
                });

                x.RunAsLocalSystem();
                x.SetServiceName("TimerTest");
            });
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            LogManager.GetLogger("MyLog").Info("stopping");
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            XmlConfigurator.Configure();

            LogManager.GetLogger("MyLog").Info("starting");

            new Thread(StartServiceCode).Start();
        }

        public void StartServiceCode()
        {
            try
            {
                LogManager.GetLogger("MyLog").Info("throwing");

                throw new ApplicationException();
            }
            finally
            {
                LogManager.GetLogger("MyLog").Info("finally");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

outputs

```
starting
throwing
stopping
```

EDIT: Please comment why you are downgrading, maybe you don't understand the problem? I see a big problem here. You write some domain logic that does important stuff in the finally clause on Exception. Then if you host the logic in a Windows Service the design suddenly is broken.

Comment: How do you know it's not executing?  Have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: Logging tells me, and yes also if you use your debugger.

Comment: Does it step into the finally block - so not executing. Or could it be an issue with not logging.

Comment: An exception in a worker thread unconditionally terminates your app.  Not writing an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException is never not a mistake.

Comment: IMHO It has nothing to do with CurrentDomain.UnhandledException. If i add such this will be executed, but that does not explain why the finally block is not executed.

Comment: @PaulF, trust me it is not executed and the logger works fine. But please, try it out yourself.

Comment: Just trying to make sure it is not an issue with writing to a log on the worker thread rather than the main thread.

Comment: "Unconditionally terminates" is just what it sounds like.  Bam, over, the end.  Your finally block does not execute.  As you found out.

Comment: @HansPassant, yes that surely is what's happening. But where do I find documentation that this is to be expected? Is it only the Windows Service and Timers combination? etc.

Comment: Just for fun, have you tried adding `Debug.WriteLine()` traces next to your existing logging, and seeing if you get something from the finally block that way?  I'm just wondering if it's not something to do with asynchronous logging giving the wrong impression.  I may be way off, but just a thought.

Comment: Same observation here. His solution was to add a catch block http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/504211/Topshelf-e-splusWindowsplusServiceplusandplu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From MDSN [try-finally (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx)

> **Within a handled exception**, the associated **finally block is guaranteed to be run**. However, if the exception is unhandled, execution of the finally block is dependent on how the exception unwind operation is triggered. That, in turn, is dependent on how your computer is set up. For more information, see [Unhandled Exception Processing in the CLR](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=128371).
>
> **Usually, when an unhandled exception ends an application, whether or not the finally block is run is not important**

This is by design, .NET has chosen to terminate your application, reason is, there is something terribly wrong, something didn't work as expected, by calling finally, we don't want to do more damage, so best is to end the application.

What if finally throws one more exception, where does that go? If application is about to close, it may have closed or started closing managed resources and accessing them for logging in finally could turn out to be fatal as well.

Comment: Thanks. So lock (obj) { } is also a broken design since this is just Monitor.Enter / Exit in a try-finally.

Comment: Not really, if application is shutting down, Monitor will be destroyed automatically so you don't need to close it. Operating system will close all locks, resources opened by the process when process exits.

Comment: But all subsequent code can not take the lock, e.g. the code in the Stop event which is executed last.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about this being an answer, but couldn't comment.
I couldn't find anything specific about the windows service, but I'm assuming it uses background/foreground threading to execute the code.

And in terms of threading, the finally block is sometimes voided (if the thread is aborted or interrupted unexpectedly) -
http://blog.goyello.com/2014/01/21/threading-in-c-7-things-you-should-always-remember-about/

Or for a more official post - (Look for the foreground/background threading section)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596527570-03-19.aspx

Hopefully it helps you a little

Comment: I agree, it it has something to do with the thread being aborted by the Windows Service environment. But why is the thread not allowed to complete it's finally block? The Exception is happening within the Thread. The Exception is not happening outside the thread where it would make perfect sense to abort the Thread at any time and fulfill a process exit.

Answer (score 2):

Have you made sure that the logger is getting a chance to flush to disk before the logger is destroyed when the service stops?

Edit

When a service starts it happens on a new thread. Within the Topshelf code there is an AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CatchUnhandledException; handler.

```
    void CatchUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        _log.Fatal("The service threw an unhandled exception", (Exception)e.ExceptionObject);

        HostLogger.Shutdown();

        if (e.IsTerminating)
        {
            _exitCode = TopshelfExitCode.UnhandledServiceException;
            _exit.Set();

#if !NET35
            // it isn't likely that a TPL thread should land here, but if it does let's no block it
            if (Task.CurrentId.HasValue)
            {
                return;
            }
#endif

            // this is evil, but perhaps a good thing to let us clean up properly.
            int deadThreadId = Interlocked.Increment(ref _deadThread);
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Unhandled Exception " + deadThreadId.ToString();
            while (true)
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
        }
    }
```

This catches the unhandled exception, and stops the service by setting the manualresetevent (this is the only thing that is blocking the service from ending).

After sleep is called, the thread is signalled and your finally block, which is on the service thread is killed.

The code then exits.

This is wired up in the Run() method in ConsoleRunHost.

```
    public TopshelfExitCode Run()
    {
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CatchUnhandledException;

        if (_environment.IsServiceInstalled(_settings.ServiceName))
        {
            if (!_environment.IsServiceStopped(_settings.ServiceName))
            {
                _log.ErrorFormat("The {0} service is running and must be stopped before running via the console",
                    _settings.ServiceName);

                return TopshelfExitCode.ServiceAlreadyRunning;
            }
        }

        bool started = false;
        try
        {
            _log.Debug("Starting up as a console application");
            _log.Debug("Thread.CurrentThread.Name");
            _log.Debug(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
            _exit = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            _exitCode = TopshelfExitCode.Ok;

            Console.Title = _settings.DisplayName;
            Console.CancelKeyPress += HandleCancelKeyPress;

            if (!_serviceHandle.Start(this))
                throw new TopshelfException("The service failed to start (return false).");

            started = true;

            _log.InfoFormat("The {0} service is now running, press Control+C to exit.", _settings.ServiceName);

            _exit.WaitOne();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Error("An exception occurred", ex);

            return TopshelfExitCode.AbnormalExit;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (started)
                StopService();

            _exit.Close();
            (_exit as IDisposable).Dispose();

            HostLogger.Shutdown();
        }

        return _exitCode;
    }
```

There is no guarantee that finally will be called for certain exceptions.

Comment: I'm using FileAppender which has implicit flush. Also, i original discovered this behavior with a dead lock due to a Monitor.Exit in the finally block. The debugger also shows the same, the finally block is never executed.

Comment: Also read this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/504211/Topshelf-e-splusWindowsplusServiceplusandplu

Answer (score 2):

Since this program runs as a Windows service it is managed by Windows.  Windows detects that something went wrong because of the `ApplicationException` call and it sends `Stop` to the service which abort the thread before the `finally` block is executed.

**The "finally" block is never executed because Windows pulls the rug from under**.  This is pefectly logical when you remind how exception handling works :

```
try {
  // Do stuff
} catch (Exception e) {
  // Executed first
} finally {
  // Executed last
}
```

Since you didn't provide a `catch` block the `ApplicationException` is propagated up to the other layers and ultimately to Windows service management which handle it by sending the `stop` request thus aborting the thread.

**Side notes :**

- Unmanaged exception in a service is very bad : obviously you should add a `catch` block and log exceptions.
- Normally the `Stop` function is used to tell the working thread it needs to stop.  This will give the thread a chance to stop in clean way.  Here is a [good example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033431/1980659).

**Edit :**

Here is a sample of what I would do.  It is more like pseudo-code but you should get the idea.

```
public void StartServiceCode(object state)
{
  bool stopTimer = false;
  try
  {
    LogManager.GetLogger("MyLog").Info("Locking");
    lock (thisLock) {
      LogManager.GetLogger("MyLog").Info("Throwing");
      throw new ApplicationException();
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // The lock is relased automatically
    // Logging the error (best practice)
    LogManager.GetLogger("MyLog").Info("Exception occurred...");
    // If severe, we need to stop the timer
    if (e is StackOverflowException || e is OutOfMemoryException) stopTimer = true;
  } finally {
    // Always clean up
    LogManager.GetLogger("MyLog").Info("finally");
  }
  // Do we need to stop?
  if (stopTimer) {
    LogManager.GetLogger("MyLog").Info("Severe exception : stopping");
    // You need to keep a reference to the timer. (yes, a timer can stop itself)
    timer.Stop();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So lock (obj) { } is also a broken design since this is just Monitor.Enter / Exit in a try-finally

Comment: I don't get it.  Do you also have a problem with `lock`?

Comment: The lock syntax is only syntactic sugar for try-finally with Monitor.Enter / Exit. So if an Exception occurs the lock is never released. In my Windows Service stop event i take the same lock to clean up stuff, and then a dead lock occurs.

Comment: Just catch the exception : you'll be able to log the error, the finally code will be executed, the service won't be stopped immediately by Windows, the [lock will be released](http://stackoverflow.com/q/590159/1980659) and you'll avoid dead locks.

Comment: Logging the error is not enough in my case - and in most cases I think. I want the service to stop and do a restart.

Answer (score 1):

The linked article explains why the finally block of a method run into a windows service provided by TopShelf library that raises an unhandled exception, it isn't executed: https://lowleveldesign.wordpress.com/2012/12/03/try-finally-topshelf-winsvc/

The problem seems related to a portion of code in the topshelf library that sleeps the thread that has raised the exception.

*Follows an excerpt of the code responsible for the sleep call on the thread, this method belongs to TopShelf library*

```
    ...
    void CatchUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        _log.Error("The service threw an unhandled exception", (Exception)e.ExceptionObject);

        ...

        int deadThreadId = Interlocked.Increment(ref _deadThread);
        Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Unhandled Exception " + deadThreadId.ToString();
        while (true)
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
    }
    ...
```